# Micronaut Data 4 and JDBC

Tags: kotlin, micronaut, micronaut-data

I am upgrading my application to Micronaut 4 and after I made the changes as described in the Micronaut guide

The application starts-up properly but when I try to retrieve data from a SQL Server I am getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "DefaultDispatcher-worker-1" io.micronaut.context.exceptions.ConfigurationException: No backing TransactionOperations configured. Check your configuration and try again
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NoSuchBeanException: No bean of type [io.micronaut.transaction.TransactionOperations] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.newNoSuchBeanException(DefaultBeanContext.java:2773)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.newNoSuchBeanException(DefaultApplicationContext.java:304)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2735)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1729)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:856)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:841)
    at io.micronaut.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionOperationsRegistry.provideSynchronous(DefaultTransactionOperationsRegistry.java:49)
```

The method that is causing the issue is like:

```
    @jakarta.transaction.Transactional
    fun loadIndex(index: String) = runBlocking {
        logger.info { "Starting load..." }
        loadRepository.pullLoadRecords()
    }
```

I have declared the datasources in the application.yaml file as usual and also the application used to work perfectly before the upgrade so I am guessing I am doing something wrong with the Micronaut 4 upgrade.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add the library:

io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-tx-jdbc

which provides the implementation class of TransactionOperatios that was missing.